# Unable to make http call from c# DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have created a `c#` library in Visual Studio 2019 on my mac. I am trying to expose a method in my `dll` which should have the capacity to make an `http` call and return the response.

But I am getting the error `Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type`.

I am very new to `c#`, so I just copy-pasted code from online. Please show me what wrong I am doing.

My Library,

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ImageTrainer
{
public class Trainer
{
    public static void TrainImage()
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.abcd.com/rest/city/search/Bang");

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        // // request.ContentLength = DATA.Length;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        // // requestWriter.Write(DATA);
        requestWriter.Close();

        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        //     responseReader.Close();
        //     Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
}
```

and I am using the library in another console application.

```
using System;
using ImageTrainer;
namespace ImageTrainerTest
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Trainer.TrainImage();
    }
}
}
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: HTTP `GET` requests cannot have a body. So also a `Content-Type` header dosn't make sense. You probably want a `POST`. Or don't send a body. Or you maybe want an `Accept` header to tell the server that you expect the response's body to be JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these 2 lines:

```
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
requestWriter.Close();
```

As you are making GET request, you should not have any body, otherwise you should use POST verb.